# How can I get the selected Item or Selected Index of the pressed Item in ListView?

Tags: listview, selecteditem, selectedindex

How can I get the selected Item or Selected Index of the pressed Item in ListView that have pressed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The ListView should have a property to reach that value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: After knowing the SelectedIndex (int) you can call the list and provide its int to reach the object stored in that postition.